# Proper query for finding all objects based on has many relation

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

Hello I've met a problem with finding the best solution to find and count all cars which are currently available for reservation. I mean that there is such relation between Car model and Reservation model:

```
Reservation.belongsTo(Car);
Car.hasMany(Reservation, {foreignKey: { allowNull: false }});
```

Then I need to find all cars which are available to reserve by a user in period of time he/she chose. For example let's imagine this situation:
We have got 3 cars A, B, C and:

car A: has now two reservations - from 10.10.2016 to 13.10.2016 and from 17.10.2016 - 18.10.2016

car B: has one reservation - 8.10.2016 - 11.10.2016

car C: one reservation - 15.10.2016 - 16.10.2016

User wants to reserve a car FROM 12.10.2016 TO 16.10.2016.

As a result, he should receive only one car to choose: CAR B

Ive created such query to get this result:

```
  var results = await Car.findAndCountAll({
    include: [{
      model: Reservation,
      where: {
        $not: {
          $or: [
            {
              dateIn: {
                $between: [chosenIn, chosenOut],
              }
            },
            {
              dateOut: {
                $between: [chosenIn, chosenOut],
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      required: true
    }],
  });
```

But everythings works good when every car has only one reservation. In case I've shown the result would be Car Car B and Car A with available reservation from 17.10.2016 - to 18.10.2016. I dont know why a car with more than one reservation is treated as 'separate body' not like one car. It's obvious that this query select all cars fullfilling at least one Reservation belonging to them. They should be listed only when they all Reservations are fullfilled. But unfortunately I cannot overcome this problem by this ORM, I also couldnt get needful informations in Sequelize docs. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.findAll()` to query and then get count of cars through `cars.length`. result will contain unique cars with array of reservations.

And add one more expression to where to avoid situations like this:
if you chose 09.10.2016-10.10.2016 dates, your query will return carB even it has reservation in this time

```
where:{
    $not: {
      $or: [
        {
          dateIn: {
            $between: [chosenIn, chosenOut],
          }
        },
        {
          dateOut: {
            $between: [chosenIn, chosenOut],
          }
        },
        $and: [
          {
              dateIn: {
                  $lt: chosenIn,
              }
          },
          {
              dateOut: {
                  $gt: chosenIn,
              }
          },
        ]
      ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup logging which should include generated SQL which will give you insight into this issue:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
    logging: console.log
    logging: function (str) {
        // do your own logging
    }
});
```